# How can I find which classes implement a given interface in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, interface

I have a solution. 
I have an interface. 
I have several classes that implement the interface.

I can use "Find All References" in order to find where the interface is implemented, but it also returns results where the interface is the return type, or where a class explicitly implements an interface's method.

Is there a better way to quickly/easily find which classes implement the interface?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620376/how-do-you-find-all-implementations-of-an-interface

Comment: So it appears that currently (without buying add ons) this is not possible in Visual Studio. This is a very expensive tool and yet it lacks this helpful feature. I don't get why people are so in love with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) (which *used* to be free) will show you this; load the dll and find the interface (F3) - expand the "Derived Types" node.

Comment: In the case of a website, where classes (can) live in the App_Code directory, what then?

Comment: I can't say - I haven't used "web site" in a few years, preferring "web application project".

Comment: Reflector is not longer free :(

Comment: Productivity Power Tools are free from Visual Studio Gallery., up to answer by sennett on this page.

Comment: @Arjang indeed; things change. It was free at the time, though. I've updated the answer

Comment: I don't think he is referring to third party dll's here.

Comment: how do you expand the "Derived Types"?

Comment: @sergtk How do you use ILSpy to do this? I don't see "Derived Types" anywhere.

Comment: @xr280xr Find and expand interface on left pane. You will see "Base Types", "Derived types" under this interface. This is in ILSpy version 2.3.1.1855. You can see how it looks like on the picture http://postimg.org/image/5ijbp5a49/ (I filled namespace and class names - you will see them in your dll)

Answer (score 8):

Using VS2010, with [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) (free) installed:

1. Leave debug mode if necessary
2. Hover over a reference to the interface
3. Expand the drop down that appears
4. "Implemented By"

Comment: Not for Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 2):

Why not just search in the entire solution for this:

```
\:.*MyInterface
```

and enable regular expressions in the search box - that ought to do the job.

Edit: Fixed the regex, it was for java before, whoops.

Comment: Not in C#; and there isn't a simple yet reliable version of : IMyInterface - it could be : SomeClass, IMyInterface | : SomeClass, ISomethingElse, IMyInterface, : SomeClass where T : IMyInterface, etc

Comment: IMyInterface was just an example - as SkippyFire says he has an interface, I presume he has a specific interface, and thus a name for it.

The regex search really should work, it works for me in Visual Studio 2008.

I've just edited the expression, as the other one was for Java - my bad.

Comment: Sorry for the many comments, I totally misread your comment, and I can see be re-reading it, that you have a good point.

However the regex is sound enough for SomeClass: ISomething, IMyInterface

But with generic constraints we have a problem.

It could easily be done, if visual studio implemented a proper regex engine for search'n'replace, but alas it doesn't :-(

Answer (score 1):

Using the "Go to Inheritor" feature in [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper) or a similar plugin would do the trick.