# Is there a way to navigate to real implementation of method behind an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, when you right-click a method call, you go to the implementation of that method inside a class except if you access this method through an interface: in that case you go to the interface method not to the actual implementation.

Is there a way / tips (key shortcut or anything) to access this actual implementation ? Otherwise you are stuck to add some comment just to remember where you did implement it that's really not productive and error prone !

Update: interesting answers but I'm not really satisfied because all are cumbersome. I will give a precise example:

```
IInterface iInterface = someObject;                        
iInterface.someMethod();
```

Actually if Visual Studio was just a little bit clever to look just one line above the method call it would see where's the real object is. And that would save me a lot of keystrokes and avoid to use "find all references" and then scan the lines with my tired eyes to see which line contain the right one :)

Comment: How would it know which implementation you wanted to see? (I can view the type hierarchy to find all known implementations, but that may be a ReSharper feature... I'm not sure.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: How about, if right-clicking an interface instance which is within scope, having an option to view the method associated with that particular instance?

Comment: @supercat: Do you mean while debugging?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yeah.  Not a universally-applicable situation, but one which would be handy often enough.

Comment: ReSharper implements it by supplying a list of implementations to choose from where it can't detect the specific one. Nice feature and I do miss it as the "Find All References" brings back too much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 extension for Go To Interface Implementation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247844/visual-studio-2010-extension-for-go-to-interface-implementation)

Comment: First time ever I have seen, Jon Skeet is saying "I'm not sure." for a  C# question in SO.

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT, LOL, but I hope you are aware that this is not really a C# question.  It is an IDE question AND Jon's "not sure" comment was regarding a specific third party plugin, i.e. ReSharper.

Comment: @MuthuGanapathyNathan He was probably trying to look like he is human for once.

Comment: Ctrl + F12 is shortcut in VS-2015

Comment: **See Also**: [How do you find all implementations of an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/620376/1366033)

Answer (score 295, accepted):

I do the following:

1) Right click on the method and click "View call hierarchy" (or shortcut Ctrl+K, Ctrl+T)

2) Expand the "Implements x" folder which will then show you all the implementations of that method.  Click on one to go there.

Relatively quick and easy.  Annoyingly though there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for the interface itself.

---

**update**: as of Visual Studio 2015 update 1, right click on a method and select go to implementation. You can also map it to keyboard shortcut via Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard and search for Edit.GoToImplementation command. The default shortcut is `Ctrl+F12`. (`F12` will navigate to the interface).

---

Comment: Good workaround. I am sticking to that when I don't have Resharper

Comment: I'm able to skip step 1. Just "View call hierarchy" (or shortcut Ctrl+K, Ctrl+T) right from where you are working and skip the interface all together. I'm in VS 2013.

Comment: Is there any hotkey to Peak the implementation? I tried ALT-CTRL-F12 with no success. (Peak is ALT-F12)

Answer (score 51):

With VS2013 one can place cursor over the method, and use Navigate To... (CTRL+,), and it will display all locations where the name is declared. Doesn't work well if different interfaces uses the same method names.

With [VS2015 Update 1](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-update1-vs) there is now a new shortcut called "Go To Implementation".

Comment: You can use Alt+End if you're using resharper.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I am using VS Express 2013 for Web.

Comment: I find this as the simplest soln, without taking your handsoff from keyboard. Thanks Rolf

Comment: This is the quickest solution possible.

Comment: @brechtvhb You can also set this to be Alt+End without R# by customising the keyboard shortcut for command `Edit.NavigateTo` :)

Answer (score 18):

I created a free extension for Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 called Inheritance Margin to provide this specific feature, as well as give a clear indication when a method implements an interface method due to a signature match. In the current version, you can right click on any glyph to get a menu of items to navigate to.

[Inheritance Margin - Visual Studio Gallery](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamHarwell.InheritanceMargin)

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a55d546-0cb2-4991-a002-e6be8ce09f08/image/file/58119/5/screenshot.png?Id=58119))</sub>

Comment: The resharper trial has expired at work, tried this extension and it rocks! thanks dude

Answer (score 15):

Right-click then "Find All References".

This will display the line of code for all the places where the method is used including the interface declaration and implementations of the interface method.  You can then click on the line to jump to the code location.

Comment: This does not give the imlpementation.

Comment: @Robaticus actually, it does. It's not the most convenient way, but the implementations will be mixed in with all the other references.

Comment: That's the only thing I do right now but it's tiresome above all as I don't have good eyes :)

Comment: An alternative to finding symbols is the call hierarchy.  It has the methods grouped in a folder structure: Calls To '...', Calls From '...' and Implements '...'

Comment: I marked your answer as right one though it's not what I wanted but it's the fault of Microsoft not yours :)

Comment: Shortcut-key for "Find All References" is `Shift + F12`.

Answer (score 14):

#### Update for Visual Studio 2015 - [Release 1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-update-1-rc/)

You can use `Edit.GoToImplementation` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

It will lead you to implementation just like it will lead you to non interface methods using <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Comment: this shortcut works fine at vscode with typescript.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the version of Visual Studio that you have, I'll say conditionally "yes."

I'm currently operating on Ultimate, and don't have other versions to verify this.  That said, within Ultimate, you can use the Architecture Explorer to find implementations.  It's a little more involved than the right click method, but here's how it works.

- Go to `View->Architecture Explorer` (or CTRL-W, N)
- Click on Class View and find the namespace that contains your interface in the list that opens.
- To the right of the namespace list, is a vertical button that says `Types`.  Click this
- Select `Interfaces`
- Choose your interface from the list
- A vertical button that says `Members` will then appear to the right.  Click that button
- Choose `Implemented by` (under `Inbound Navigation`) and that will provide a list of implementations of your interface.
- Double clicking on the implementation will take you to the class.

Comment: I'm fairly sure Architecture Explorer is Ultimate edition only, but this will work.

Comment: Thanks quite good I thumbed up but in this context I want be quick to change my code.

Answer (score 8):

Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 (released December 2015) has now added a right click 'Go To Implementation' feature as standard.

Answer (score 6):

Within 2012 Ultimate, you can search the interface in solution explorer. Right-click the interface and choose "Derived Types", the implemented classes will shown in solution explorer. Not sure if it works in express.

Comment: Didn't notice that. Thanks.
<br/>
Now if there was only a way to get the solution explorer to open it's tree to the currently displayed file so I don't have first bring up the tooltip of the editor to get the file's path so as to derive then navigate through the solution explorer to the source file, where I can the determine the list of implemented-by's for the interface...

Source code navigation should become a more important feature I think.

Comment: -- Just discovered the "Ctrl + ], S" command which expands the solution explorer tree to the current edit document (sync with active document). The resultant file node may then be expanded to expose the contained types which in turn may be right clicked to access the context menu containing the 'Derived Types' command.  
  
Nice.

Comment: @George, you can also have Visual Studio ALWAYS track the current open file in the solution explorer via Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General -> "Track active item in solution explorer"

Comment: VS2012 Premium has this feature too. In **VS2015** Enterprise, this '**Derived Types**' feature has been split to two features '**Derived Types**' & '**Implemented By**', even nicer _:)_

Answer (score 5):

For people who use Resharper, pressing CTRL + F12 will make you go directly to the class method!

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. What you are describing would make sense only if the interface would be limited to 1 implementation.

Consider this example:

```
interface IWrite 
{ 
 void Write(); 
}
class A : IWrite { 
  public void Write() { Console.WriteLine("A"); } 
}
class B : IWrite { 
  public void Write() { Console.WriteLine("B"); } 
}
class X : IWrite { 
  private readonly string _x;
  public X(string x) {
    _x = x;
  } 
  public void Write() { Console.WriteLine(_x); } 
}

class UseIWrite()
{
  public void Use(IWrite iwrite) 
  {
     iwrite.Write();
  }
}
```

If you use *go to implementation* of Write in UseIWrite, it takes you to the declaration of the interface, because at that point any of the IWrite implementations could be passed into the method.

Thankfully some tools like for example ReSharper offer you to *find all usages* of the method, so you can easily navigate to the desired implementation.

Comment: …and if there is only one implementation, R# will take you straight there without further ado.

Comment: It's not free, but neither is Visual Studio.  How much is your time worth? :)

Comment: It's not that I don't want to pay, It's on the principle: this is quite basic common sense feature, it is shamefull you have to pay once more when you already paid for VS :)

Comment: @user310291 While I agree with you, not buying the product that does exactly the feature you want in order to "punish" a third party for not providing it out of the box, is cutting off your nose to spite your face.

Comment: Resharper provides this without having to show all usages. You can select which implementation you want to go to.

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio with Update 1 now implements this feature! Just right click the member and you should see "Go to implementation" right under "Go to definition".

Answer (score 2):

Check out this new free Visual Studio 2013 Extension - [Implementator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/39eddcfe-7204-409e-b0ea-11f01d73b4d8).
It adds option "Go to implementation" to Visual Studio editor context menu.

It is not so reliably and fast as Resharper, but does it's job just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Going to the declaration will open up the interface method. Going to the implementation, will take you, or list for you, the classes that implement the code for that interface method (not the interface method itself).

**Update**

As Jon Skeet pointed out in the comments (and I missed before answering), the feature I've described might be a ReSharper feature...not a Visual Studio one.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio can only tell you where it is referenced, but this may be too coarse.

There are other tools that can tell you more about the structure of your application, including which class implements which interface, which method overrules which other method, and so on.  I personally prefer using Understand For C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible, despite the elaborate in memory code structure maintained by VS, code navigation is rather...stingy.

It seems the only alternative is a global search with "Find All Reference" followed by a manual search of the resulting list to exclude typed value declarations, conversions, etc. or the use of other tools within VS other than the code editor. All rather complex and disappointing.