# Is there a way in VS debugger to jump to the definition of the implementing method if type is an interface?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio: Is there a way to navigate to real implementation of method behind an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662784/visual-studio-is-there-a-way-to-navigate-to-real-implementation-of-method-behin)

When debugging in VS I often use the F12/Goto Definition to get to code as opposed to actually stepping into it.

When I'm dealing with a concrete class it's fine but when I'm dealing with an interface I end up not jumping to the method definition (in my mind this is the code that runs) but the method signature in the interface.

Is there any way to tell the debugger to jump me to the actual implemenation of the method as opposed to the definition of the method signature in the interface?  I would think the debugger should know this at runtime, right?

Comment: [This thread][1] deals with a similar matter. This one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261567/how-do-you-quickly-find-the-implementations-of-an-interfaces-method) does as well. Another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247844/visual-studio-2010-extension-for-go-to-interface-implementation


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662784/visual-studio-is-there-a-way-to-navigate-to-real-implementation-of-method-behin

Comment: Resharper has an option for this - sadly it is a commercial tool that costs a small amount.