# See implementation of interface on VS

Tags: c#, eclipse, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, shortcut

I use to develop with eclipse and am missing some things on VisualStudio 2013

As you can see in the gif below, I can use a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> shortcut to see which classess are imlpementing my **interface IFoo**  so I can see the details (in this case Microwave51 class)..How can I do the same trick on VS-2013,

[This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/620376/982161) is pretty good but only since 2015

[image]

## Edit:

If I do Right click on the interface declaration and click "Go To Implementation" I get only this:

[image]

Comment: You're missing an option, make sure you right click on the interface itself. Also, I notice you have an option to view a designer, is this a WinForm app or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you have ReSharper...
Right click on the interface declaration and click "Go To Implementation."

If you don't...
Right click on the interface and "Find All References." Gotta look through the results manually.